# Annotation @Dispose calls the method to clean up resources 2 times. Jakarta EE

Tags: java, web, jakarta-ee

I use the @Dispose annotation, which should call a method to clean up the resources created by the @Produces annotation, for some reason the inscription "cleaned" is output to the console 2 times, not 1. Why?

```
@WebServlet(value = "/tes")
public class MyTag extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    @Named("Person")
    Person person;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                         HttpServletResponse resp) {
        System.out.println(person.name);
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
class Producer {
    @Produces
    @Named("Person")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return new Person("Max");
    }
    public void clean(@Disposes Person person) {
        person.clean();
    }
}

class Person {
    String name;
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void clean() {
        System.out.println("cleaned");
    }
}
```